# Upgraded to 1.9.2 gives an error

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, installation

Today I have upgraded my store to 1.9.2, but it is giving an error page.

I have try to cross check the same using error log.

it is giving me below error.

2014-09-17T08:36:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: script_name  in /home/Store_name/public_html/errors/processor.php on line 445

Comment: Have you re-indexed and cleared cache?

Comment: This is probably not the error causing the error page. This is just a "notice" while processing the error into a report, stored in `var/report/`. You should check the `var/report/` dir for error reports that contain the real error.